# How to fetch value from sqlite using ID?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am successfully able to add data to sqlite database,
now when i click on a listview item,
i want to get data from sqlite table ID which is same as listview position

:
[My Database looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQnH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separately query for getting raw at particular position clicked in `LisView`.

```
    int id = 0; // id of clicked item
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ").append(id);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query.toString(), null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, IntentClass.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",id);
        intent.putExtra("link",cursor.getString(4));
        intent.putExtra("lid",cursor.getString(5));
        intent.putExtra("lpass",cursor.getString(6));
        intent.putExtra("laddInfo",cursor.getString(7));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    cursor.close();
```